# Map Projection is not working as expected when zoom level is not the same

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show the user location on top of the drawer that I have in my app instead of center of the map since the drawer covers part of the map :

```
fun centerMap(height: Int, drawerHeight: Int) {
        LocationDataProvider.location?.let {
            val length = ((height - drawerHeight) / 2) + (drawerHeight - (height / 2))
            val point = googleMap.projection.toScreenLocation(LatLng(it.lat, it.lng))
            Log.d("Ali", "${point.y.toString()},  ${point.x.toString()}")
            val newY = point.y + length
            val newLatLng = googleMap.projection.fromScreenLocation(Point(point.x, newY))
            moveCamera(newLatLng)
        }
    }
```

`LocationDataProvider.location` returns center of the map. Here is `moveCamera` method :

```
fun moveCamera(location: LatLng) {
        val cameraUpdate: CameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            location, 18F
        )
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)
        googleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this@MapController)
    }
```

In my logic CenterMap method is called every 5 seconds.The problem is first it zooms somewhere over ocean and then immediately in 5 seconds, it zooms on the desired location (top of the drawer). Here is the log result of `centerMap` method every 5 seconds (`"${point?.y.toString()},  ${point?.x.toString()}"`):

```
D/Ali: 468,  1344
D/Ali: -18826752,  4133
D/Ali: 418,  542
D/Ali: 419,  539
...
```

As you see as a result of first log, it moves over ocean, from the second log it moves to desired location, and from there, it will be on desired location.

I concluded that when zoom level is not `18f`, projection is not working as expected, so if I use following method, and then use projection, it works as expected :

```
fun centerMap() {
        LocationDataProvider.location?.let {
            moveCamera(LatLng(it.lat, it.lng))
        }
    }
```

That means `moveCamera` method will be called twice, but is there any solution that projection works as expected without considering zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can use [map padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/configure-map#set_up_map_padding) `GoogleMap.setPadding()`:

> public void setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
>
> Sets padding on the map.
>
> This method allows you to define a visible region on the map, to
> signal to the map that portions of the map around the edges may be
> obscured, by setting padding on each of the four edges of the map. Map
> functions will be adapted to the padding. For example, the zoom
> controls, compass, copyright notices and Google logo will be moved to
> fit inside the defined region, camera movements will be relative to
> the center of the visible region, etc.